# Load shared library from distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a shared library that I copied to hdfs at

```
/user/uokuyucu/lib/libxxx.so
```

and I have a `WordCount.java` with the identical code from tutorial plus my own `FileInputFormat` class called `MyFileInputFormat` that has nothing in it except the constructor modified as follows:

```
public MyInputFileFormat() {
            System.loadLibrary("xxx");  
}
```

and I'm also adding my shared library to distributed cache like this in job setup (main):

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/uokuyucu/lib/libxxx.so"),           
job.getConfiguration());
```

I run it as;

```
hadoop jar mywordcount.jar mywordcount.WordCount input output
```

and got `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no far_jni_interface in java.library.path` exception.

How can I load a shared library in my hadoop job?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but the docs also configure symlinking: see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/native_libraries.html#Native+Shared+Libraries